# Is there a way to get the functionality of ML Kit in the web browser?

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition, firebase-mlkit

I'm developing a cross-platform app (iOS/Android/web) and am loving the fast, cheap on-device image labeling feature of ML Kit on mobile. Is there a way to replicate the behavior on the web? Are the ML Kit models available for re-use with a different ML library so it can be repurposed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not seem like ML Kit allows you to export models created using it, only import models. However, tensorflow.js lets you run TensorFlow models on the web. If you are looking for an easy way to create models there are several web-based programs which allow you to easily create ML models and export as TensorFlow Lite (which can be run in tensorflow.js or even hosted on Firebase). A couple I have heard of are: lobe.ai and ml5.js. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I run TensorFlow Lite files on tensorflow.js?